# Reference switch: which position and NC or NO?

Tags: switches, reference, position

I have a small linear axis, which is operated with a stepper motor.

I need a reference switch to determine the position. My question is, do I run this switch as normally closed or normally open?

Also, where should I install this reference switch at the end or at the beginning from the axis?

Comment: I think you know best what reference you need, start or end. And there is no way to figure out if normally closed or open is better with no other info.

Answer (score 0):

Normally closed may be safer as the drive would stop if the connection to the switch breaks. You'll need to check which polarity your controller expects.

Install the reference switch at the end you want the carriage to move towards on power-up reset. Usually that will be the "home" position.